# Cannot run the code due to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, noclassdeffounderror, jsprit

I am investigating the [jsprit](http://github.com/jsprit) library. For this I just created a new project in Eclipse and copied-pasted the [demo example class](http://github.com/jsprit/jsprit/blob/v1.6/jsprit-examples/src/main/java/jsprit/examples/SimpleExample.java). Then I added all jars to the path, including `log4j-1.2.17.jar`. Nevrtheless I cannot execute the demo code due to the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager
    at jsprit.core.problem.vehicle.VehicleImpl$Builder.<clinit>(VehicleImpl.java:108)
    at com.test.jsprit.main(jsprit.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

What does it actually mean and how to solve this issue? Does it mean that some other *.jar file is missed?

UPDATE:

The error occurs at the following line:

```
Builder vehicleBuilder = VehicleImpl.Builder.newInstance("vehicle");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong version of the log4j lib. You need the 2.x version.

See:

[LogManager (Version 1.x)](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/LogManager.html)

[LogManager (Version 2.x)](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

`log4j-1.2.17.jar` implements log4j version 1 and its pretty old. What you need is implementation of log4j 2 - add this as the dependency: [link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core)